# Array.prototype.slice - what if the end param is greater than the array length?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can't find it - what if the `end` param passed to `Array.prototype.slice` is greater than array length?

I've tested it and it works (in Chrome), but I'm not sure if this is standard behaviour thus can be used commonly?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If `end` is greater than the length of the array, it uses the length of the array.  From [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.slice):

> If relativeEnd < 0, let final be max((len + relativeEnd),0); **else let final be min(relativeEnd, len).**

So yes, it's standard behaviour that can be used.

---

Addressing this part of your question:

> I can't find it

I find the quickest way is to search for "mdn array slice" - the first result is usually the relevant documentation page on the Mozilla Developer Network, in this case, [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).  Each of these pages has a [specifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Specifications) section, which links through to the right part of the spec.  It takes a little bit of getting used to how to read the specs, but it's sometimes useful to dive into them.

Comment: Thx, I've been missing the specifications section, somehow, for all the time;/.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your advice about using the specifications section

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, it is as per the specification.

As per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.slice)

> 10. If relativeEnd < 0, let final be max((len + relativeEnd),0); else let final be min(relativeEnd, len).

Which means that **final** value is `min` of **relativeEnd** (end value provided as parameter) and **len** (length of array).

and

> 15. Repeat, while k < final

So, the looping is done till the `length` of array if the `end` is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

The array is only copied until `min(array.length, endArgument)`. Yes, this is [standardised in §22.1.3.22](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.slice), and can be trusted to work in every browser.